# sklearn: multi-class problem and reporting sensitivity and specificity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, supervised-learning

I have a three-class problem and I'm able to report precision and recall for each class with the below code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

which gives me the precision and recall nicely for each of the 3 classes in a table format.

My question is how can I now get sensitivity and specificity for each of the 3 classes? I looked at sklearn.metrics and I didn't find anything for reporting sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: How are sensitivity and sipacificty defined? Which metrics that sklearn is already providing could you use to calculate them on your own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we check the [help page for classification report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html):

> Note that in binary classification, recall of the positive class is
> also known as “sensitivity”; recall of the negative class is
> “specificity”.

So we can convert the pred into a binary for every class, and then use the recall results from `precision_recall_fscore_support`.

Using an example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

Looks like:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

Using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
res = []
for l in [0,1,2]:
    prec,recall,_,_ = precision_recall_fscore_support(np.array(y_true)==l,
                                                      np.array(y_pred)==l,
                                                      pos_label=True,average=None)
    res.append([l,recall[0],recall[1]])
```

put the results into a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(res,columns = ['class','sensitivity','specificity'])

    class   sensitivity specificity
0   0   0.75    1.000000
1   1   0.75    0.000000
2   2   1.00    0.666667
```

Comment: That's great. Only I think you need to switch the sensitivity and specificity values since "recall of the positive class is also known as sensitivity”. And the positive class has index 1. I also confirmed, calculating manually, that sensitivity and specificity above should be flipped. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry let me check

Comment: @miniMint i go it correct i think. so from my example above, for label 1, sensitivity is Tn / (tn + fp) , so tn = 3 , tn+fp = 3 + 1, 0.75 is correct

Comment: same thing for specificity, the prediction got none of the label 1 correct, so specificity = 0

Answer (score 0):

Classification report's output is a formatted string. This code snippet extracts the required values and stores it in a 2-D list.
Note: To understand the code better, add print statements to check the variable values.

```
y = classification_report(y_test,y_pred) #classification report's output is a string
    lines = y.split('\n') #extract every line and store in a list 
    res = [] #list to store the cleaned results 
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[i].split(" ") #Values are separated by blanks. Split at the blank spaces. 
        line = [j for j in line if j!=''] #add only the values into the list
        if len(line) != 0: 
            #empty lines get added as empty lists. Remove those 
            res.append(line)
```